# MATLAB - Eigs(A,B) when B is singular

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve an eigenvalue problem of large matrices (8000×8000). Since `A` and `B` are sparse in my case, I thought that it is better to use `eigs` than `eig`. But the problem is that `B` is singular and MATLAB's `eigs` can not handle it.

Are there are any workarounds to solve this problem?

P.S: 
Both `A` and `B` are complex and non-symmetric

Comment: Does eig solve it? (for smaller test cases)

Comment: @AlexanderKemp : Yes, it does. `eig` can handle singular matrices

Comment: @AlexanderKemp problem is, `eig` handles only real, symmetric matrices.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis : Don't you mean `eigs`? Also `eigs` can handle complex matrices. https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html#inputarg_A

Comment: @SaravanaKumar `eig` can do it for sparse, but only if they're real and symmetric. `eigs` can do it for the other case.

Comment: That's your whole conundrum isn't it? `eig(A,B)` works for sungular `B`, but `eigs(A,B)` doesn't. But, your `A` and `B` are non-symmetric and sparse and giant, so you kinda really need `eigs`

Comment: Is it just 1 problem you have, or are you solving different systems multiple times inside some algorithm? In other words, what is your use case?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis : I have written a stability code, which is general. This code will give me the matrices `A` and `B` for any case I want. I use `MATLAB` to just solve the eigenvalue problem. I hope I have answered what you asked for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying ARPACK routines leveraged by MATLAB allow solution of singular mass matrix problems (`B` to MATLAB, `M` to ARPACK). The APRACK documentation states:

> If  **M** is singular or if one is interested in eigenvalues near a point σ then a user may choose to work with **C** = (**A** - σ **M**)<sup>-1</sup>**M**

where **C** is the shifted operator. Therefore, by explicitly specifying a numerical value for the shift parameter [`sigma`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html#inputarg_sigma), [`eigs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html) can attempt to converge to the nearest dominate eigenvalue as long as the shift doesn't make **C** singular.

For example,

```
>> n = 1000;
>> A = sprandn(n,n,1/n) + speye(n,n); % ensure invertibility of A
>> B = sprandn(n,n,1/n); B(1:n-1,1:n-1) = B(1:n-1,1:n-1) + speye(n-1); % mildly pathological B
>> condest(B)
ans =
   Inf
```

`A` doesn't need to be invertible, but it will let us check our answer in a bit.  Calling `eigs` without a specified shift throws an error:

```
>> eigs(A,B,1)
Error using eigs/checkInputs/LUfactorB (line 954)
B is singular.
...
```

Specifying a shift remedies this<sup>1</sup>

```
>> eigs(A,B,1,0)
ans =
    0.1277
```

But that's only the dominate eigenvalue found near `0`.  Let's check some other points

```
>> sort(arrayfun(@(sigma)eigs(A,B,1,sigma),linspace(-10,10,10).'),'descend')
ans =
   4.1307 + 0.2335i
   4.1307 + 0.2335i
   4.1307 + 0.2335i
   3.3349 + 0.0000i
   1.1267 + 0.0000i
   0.1277 + 0.0000i
   0.1277 + 0.0000i
   0.1277 + 0.0000i
   0.1277 + 0.0000i
   0.1277 + 0.0000i
```

If looks like `4.1307 + 0.2335i` might be the dominate eigenvalue of the system.  Let's look around that point for some more eigenvalues:

```
>> eigs(A,B,5,4.13)
ans =
   4.1307 - 0.2335i
   4.1307 + 0.2335i
   3.3349 + 0.0000i
   2.8805 + 0.0000i
   2.6613 + 0.0000i
```

Looks good.  But are there bigger finite eigenvalues?  Luckily, since `A` is invertible, we can check the eigenvalues directly by taking the reciprocals of `eig(B/A)`:

```
>> lam = sort(1./eig(full(B/A)),'descend')
lam =
      Inf + 0.0000i
   4.1307 + 0.2335i
   4.1307 - 0.2335i
   3.4829 + 1.6481i
   3.4829 - 1.6481i
   3.3349 + 0.0000i
   2.4162 + 2.1442i
   2.4162 - 2.1442i
   2.8805 + 0.0000i
   2.2371 + 1.7137i
   2.2371 - 1.7137i
   ...
```

First, we see that annoying infinite eigenvalue giving all the problems.
Second, we can see that `eigs` did find the largest finite eigenvalue but *didn't find* the slightly smaller magnitude eigenvalues in the complex plane because the purely real eigenvalues were closer to the shift point:

```
>> [lam,abs(lam-4.13)]
ans =
      Inf + 0.0000i      Inf + 0.0000i
   4.1307 + 0.2335i   0.2335 + 0.0000i % found by eigs(A,B,5,4.13)
   4.1307 - 0.2335i   0.2335 + 0.0000i % found by eigs(A,B,5,4.13)
   3.4829 + 1.6481i   1.7705 + 0.0000i
   3.4829 - 1.6481i   1.7705 + 0.0000i
   3.3349 + 0.0000i   0.7951 + 0.0000i % found by eigs(A,B,5,4.13)
   2.4162 + 2.1442i   2.7450 + 0.0000i
   2.4162 - 2.1442i   2.7450 + 0.0000i
   2.8805 + 0.0000i   1.2495 + 0.0000i % found by eigs(A,B,5,4.13)
   (8 more complex eigenvalues)
   2.6613 + 0.0000i   1.4687 + 0.0000i % found by eigs(A,B,5,4.13)
```

So yes, there is a workaround.  But it requires more work to perform robustly and correctly, which is the `norm` for problems involving singular matrices.

The "best way", I would say, is that if the problem fits into memory and can be computed directly in a reasonable amount of time, do so.  Otherwise, the above shift method can supplement the work with effort.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'll note that not all values of `sigma` will work.  For the example presented above, `1` fails:

```
>> eigs(A,B,5,1)
Error using eigs/checkInputs/LUfactorAminusSigmaB (line 994)
The shifted operator is singular. The shift is an eigenvalue.
 Try to use some other shift please.
```

Do to the large number of `1` eigenvalues in the example system, the chosen shift creates a singular **C** matrix, which is not good.  Slightly moving off of this point remedies the error.